# Windows 10's backup to restore to a different version of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, backup, restore

Short question: Can Windows 10's backup restore to a different version of Windows 10? Like from Home to Pro?

Long version, because I want to complain about W10's update policy: Due to the aggravation of Windows 10's update policy that breaks her printers, I want to setup my mother-in-law with W10 Pro instead of Home. She's nowhere nearby and can't be away from her computer very long. So I'm thinking of having her backup to an external drive and send it to me so I can import it to the W10 Pro computer and then setup the new computer with a dead-link to WSUS so it will leave her alone once and for all.

Comment: You can use WSUS with Windows 10 Home. “I want to setup my mother-in-law with W10 Pro instead of Home.“ Feature updates are still required with Windows 10 Professional.  You can only defer feature updates I believe it’s 4 months.  The backup is going to be unique to that installation. What you want is possible just not without third-party tools.  Of course might be easier just to keep the current installation and configure that to use WSUS.  Of course not installing updates is a absolutely horrible idea and I cannot for ethical reasons help you do what you want

Comment: Oh, the ability to do WSUS on Home is a big oversight on my part then, making this a dumb question. Thanks for the heads up. 

And to your last point, while I tend to agree about staying patched, more pressing is the ability to use the computer on a day-to-day basis, especially when compared to the obscure risk from being unpatched -- and for her job, printing is necessary. That would be like being unable to buy groceries because I put all of my money in a vault I can't access.

Comment: Also, as I've looked into it, I don't find a direct way to set Home to WSUS. Can you point me to a post on it? Everything I see says it's not available for Home.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.tenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/10932-windows-10-home-not-connecting-intranet-wsus.html but if you are going to upgrade the license to Professional you don't need to reinstall Windows 10 you can just upgrade the current installation to Windows 10 Professional.  Research indicates I might have been thinking of solutions on Professional not Home

Comment: APPARENTLY I can use a Windows 7 Pro key and upgrade Windows 10 Home to Pro in-place! This bypasses my whole thing about setting up a new computer for her.  https://superuser.com/questions/1178778/upgrading-windows-10-home-to-pro-with-windows-7-pro-license/1178808#1178808

Comment: Free upgrade offer expired on July 29 2016

Comment: It doesn't matter. Microsoft is still letting Windows 7 keys unlock Windows 10. Both through a boot install or in-place update. I have personally done this and the link I posted above has an example of it being done too.